# Write unit test for try catch in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I have something like this in my controller:

```
public function method()
{
    try {
        $data = Model::method();

        return $data;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

while I'm looking for writing unit test for this method, in this way:

```
public function testMethod()
{
    $var = (new \App\Http\Controllers\MyController)->method();

    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

my question is when I run phpunit in code-coverage mode it returns that catch block in my controller code isn't covered.

first question is How should I do cover the catch block?

and my second question is that How I can say **$var** values equals to something which I define.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test that `$var` equals something specific you would use `$this->assertEquals(mixed $expected, mixed $actual[, string $message = ''])`

So if you expected `$var` to equal `'hello'` you would write the following:

```
$this->assertEquals('hello', $var, 'optional message to display on test failure'
```

You can read more about `assertEquals` [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.assertions.html).

In terms of you first question. If you can get the exception to be thrown via passing in a specific parameter to the controller method then that is easiest. Otherwise you need to mock the `Model` and have when the function is called, throw an exception to force the catch block to be called.

You could do it with something along the lines of:

```
    $mock = Mockery::mock('\App\Model');
    $mock->shouldReceive('method')->once()
        ->andThrow(new \Exception('Fun exception'));
    $this->app->instance('\App\Model', $mock);
```